# Binded click callback on multiple HTML element and getting the actual element clicked

Tags: jquery, onclick, this, bind

While studying the JQuery 'on' method i come to a interesting problem. I try a lot but never get any concrete way to achieve it

**What i want?**

I have a below HTML(I cannot edit anything in it)

```
    <div id='apple1' class="apple">  Apple1 </div>
    <div id='apple2' class="apple">  Apple2 </div>
    <div id='apple3' class="apple">  Apple3 </div>
```

First lets see a function, we will use this in our click callback

```
var fun = function(event) { 
    console.log('example', this);
}
```

Now lets attach it to a HTML element

```
$('.apple').on('click', fun)
```

Now after clicking Apple1 we will get this in console

```
example, <div class=".apple" id="apple1">
```

see the snnipet:

```js
var fun = function(event) { 
    console.log('example', this);
 }
$('.apple').on('click', fun)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='apple1' class="apple">  Apple1 </div>
<div id='apple2' class="apple">  Apple2 </div>
<div id='apple3' class="apple">  Apple3 </div>
```

Now i wants to bind the callback function to something else so lets change above code to:

```
var funBinded = fun.bind({name: 'JQuery'})
 $('.apple').on('click', funBinded)
```

The output will be:

```
example, >{name: 'JQuery'}
```

see the snippet:

```js
var fun = function(event) { 
    console.log('example', this);
 }
var funBinded = fun.bind({name: 'JQuery'})
$('.apple').on('click', funBinded)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='apple1' class="apple">  Apple1 </div>
<div id='apple2' class="apple">  Apple2 </div>
<div id='apple3' class="apple">  Apple3 </div>
```

Now here 'this' will point to the binded object rather then the HTML element clicked.
In the second case the click could have been trigger by any of the div ('Apple1', 'Apple2', 'Apple3').

So how would i know here that which element is clicked?

Also note that:
**I can not make any change in HTML doc, so i cannot use below approach:**

```
<div id='apple1' class="apple" onclick="fun(event, this)">  Apple1 </div>
```

**I alse do not wants to use even.target because it could give me innermost element clicked rather than the one on which event is registered**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've changed the scope the handler function runs under (through the use of `bind()`) `this` will no longer be the element which was clicked.

If you still need to get a reference to the element which the event is bound to (not the element which raised the event, as your question mentions), use the `currentTarget` property of the `event` which is passed to the event handler as an argument:

```js
var fun = function(e) {
  console.log('example', this);
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
}

var funBinded = fun.bind({
  name: 'JQuery'
})

$('.apple').on('click', funBinded)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="apple1" class="apple"><span>Apple1</span></div>
<div id="apple2" class="apple"><span>Apple2</span></div>
<div id="apple3" class="apple"><span>Apple3</span></div>
```

Note that I wrapped the text within the `.apple` elements in a `span` to show that the `currentTarget` property is returning the correct element.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It is perfectly what i wanted :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help